# Speed drops in for-loops python on rpi

Tags: python-3, processor-speed

I am working with python 3.5 on rpi 3B+ and making a led matrix project. For that I would like to know at what speed my code is running each cycle. I will take the minimum and use that as a refresh rate to get a smooth animation.
However I am a bit lost in the stability of these times. The simple code below runs at my rpi at 14.2Hz, But often drops to 7.1Hz (half(!), I tried smaller and bigger loops, always half)

Does anyone know what causes the drops in speed and what to do about it?
I already tried running it as background process or with a higher priority (nice)

Thanks in advance,

Jeroen

Edit: thanks to Joan I tried the vcgencmd get_throttled command and found out my pi was occasionally under volted and capping the frequency. Apperantely my led matrix draw a lot of current dropping the voltage. I slightly provided a bit more voltage (now at 5.27V) and the speed is stable. Thanks all for contributing!

```
import time
import numpy as np

start = time.time()
while 1:

    for x in range(100):
        for y in range(100):
            s=x**y

    print('Frequency %3.1f Hz' % (1 / (time.time() - start)))
    start = time.time()
```

Comment: just an observation ... put `start = time.time()` inside the `while` block at the top, then you can delete the last line of your program

Comment: @Jeroen, does frequency drops little by little, and steady after a number of loops?

Comment: This question is not Pi specific. There are proper code timing tools in Python.

Comment: Perhaps the busy loop causes the Pi to get hot and then the CPU is throttled.  Edit your question to include the result of `vcgencmd get_throttled`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The code above is just a cutout from my main file, therefore not optimal and it is just for reference. The frequency drops instantly and not little by little. I will try you request later today, joan, and report back here

Comment: @Jeroen, I changed you code a bit and did a test run.  You might like to let me know how to check your speed drop. 
https://penzu.com/p/70a7c808

Comment: @Jeroen, Supper time, see you late this evening or tomorrow.

Comment: @Jeroen, I wrote another version of my timing program, to test function execution time.  For example, a function looping pass 1,000 times found to be about 300 micro seconds.  So if you give me your test function ABC, I run it and will give the time elapsed. https://penzu.com/p/794c8616.

Comment: @tlfong01 the script above is the test script. I just look at the print output to know the current frequency. It drops instantly between to iteration of the while loop. It then stays at that frequency for a while until it instantly shoots up again. The CPU throttling therefore sounds plausible, still need to check it.... Not at home right know, so hopefully tomorrow.

Comment: @jeroen, Ah yes, print something takes time, so is floating point arithmetic.  Just now I found that printing 10 lines takes a couple of milliSeconds: https://penzu.com/p/ac2e5e90.  So you might like give me a "closed" function without printing, floating calculations, etc.  BTW, you seem to bash run python scripts which might be slower than running python programs direct in memory.  Also python is half compiled, half interpreted, and also dynamic typing, therefore might be a couple of times slower than a similar fully compiled, static typed C++ program.

Comment: Thanks all. Problem solved, see edit

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer so that it can be marked as accepted, thanks.